# By Bessel's inequality, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |c_n|^2 \leq \|f\|^2 < \infty$, Why $\|f\|^2 < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that $\varphi_n$ is an orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert space $H.$ Let

$$V_N = \text{span}\{\varphi_1, \varphi_2, ..., \varphi_N\}, \ V = \cup_{N=1}^\infty V_N$$

($V$ is the vector space of finite linear combinations of $\varphi_n$). Then

1. $$\{\Phi_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}^\perp = \{f \in H: \langle f, \Phi_n \rangle = 0 \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\} = \{0\}$$ i.e. if $f \in H$ and $\langle f, \Phi_n \rangle = 0$ for all $n,$ then $f =0.$

implies

2. If $f \in H$ and $s_N = \sum_{n=1}^N \langle f, \Phi_n \rangle \Phi_n,$ then $\|s_N - f\| \rightarrow 0$ as $N \rightarrow \infty.$

**Proof**

Let $f \in H$ and denote

$$c_n = \langle f, \varphi_n \rangle , \quad s_N = \sum_{n=1}^N c_n \varphi_n$$

By Bessel's inequality, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |c_n|^2 \leq \|f\|^2 < \infty$ i.e. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n |c_i|^2$ is a convergent sequence and so is a Cauchy sequence. Hence, for $M < N$ (using if $h = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \phi_n$, then $\|h\|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^N |a_n|^2$ as a consequence of Pythagorean theorem)

$$\|s_N - s_M\|^2 = \bigg\| \sum_{M+1}^N c_n \phi_n \bigg\|^2 = \sum_{M+1}^N |c_n|^2 \rightarrow 0$$

as $M, N \rightarrow \infty$. In other words, $s_N$ is a Cauchy sequence in $H$. By completeness of $H$ there is $u \in H$ such
that $\|s_N - u\| \rightarrow 0$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$. Moreover, $\forall N \geq n$

$$\langle f-s_N , \varphi_n  \rangle = 0$$

Taking the limit as $N \rightarrow \infty$ with $n$ fixed yields

$$\langle f-u, \varphi_n \rangle = 0 \quad \forall n$$

Therefore by (2), $f - u = 0$

My question is why, by Bessel's inequality,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |c_n|^2 \leq \|f\|^2 < \infty$$

I mean why exactly $\|f\|^2 < \infty$?

Comment: It is just by definition of an Hilbert space. Every element $a \in H$ has a norm $||a||$ well-defined in $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Parseval's identity. Basically the inequality becomes equality.

Comment: @velobos is this means that for any normed space , norm any element in it is finite

Comment: @Roba, the definition of a norm $N$ in a vectorial space $E$ is an application that goes from $E$ to $\mathbb{R}^+$ and that verifies the three usual propertie. You see that, by definition, for any $x \in E$, the quantity $N(x)$ has a meaning and is a positive real number.  Maybe you are mixing up with the norm $|| \cdot||_{L^2(\Omega)}$ on Lebesgue spaces. It is for that reason that the definition of  $L^2(\Omega)$ imposes that the quantity $||f||_{L^2(\Omega)}$ is finite, so that $(L^2(\Omega),|| \cdot||_{L^2(\Omega)})$ is a normed vectorial space (and Hilbert space but that's another story)